# Get list of installed apps on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

Is there a way (some API) to get the list of installed apps on an iPhone device.

While searching for similar questions, I found some thing related to `url registration`, but I think there must be some API to do this, as I don't want to do any thing with the app, I just want the list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, apps are sandboxed and Apple-accepted APIs do not include anything that would let you do that.

You can, however, test whether a certain app is installed:

- if the app is known to handle URLs of a certain type
- by using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"thisapp://foo"]`

You can get a list of apps and URL schemes from [here](http://handleopenurl.com/).

Comment: There's a slick little framework that takes care of this and checks to see what's currently running (whether it has a URL scheme or not) called iHasApp. Just learned about it: http://www.ihasapp.com/

Answer (score 4):

For jailbroken devices you can use next snipped of code:

```
-(void)appInstalledList
{
 static NSString* const path = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist";

NSDictionary *cacheDict = nil;
BOOL isDir = NO;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: path isDirectory: &isDir] && !isDir) 
{
    cacheDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];

    NSDictionary *system = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"System"]; // First check all system (jailbroken) apps
    for (NSString *key in system)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",key);
    }
    NSDictionary *user = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"User"]; // Then all the user (App Store /var/mobile/Applications) apps

    for (NSString *key in user)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",key);
    }
    return;
}
NSLog(@"can not find installed app plist");                   
}
```

Comment: Not even enter into if condition. What is the problem from my side?

Comment: @sathiamoorthy : is your device jailbroken?, above code is working only for jailbroken device

Answer (score 3):

for non jailbroken device, we can use third party framework which is called "**ihaspp**", also its free and apple accepted. Also they given good documentation how to integrate and how to use. May be this would be helpful to you. Good luck!!

https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp

Comment: Thank you, I am no longer working on it, but I will surely check it.

Comment: you are welcome brother!! definately it works, I already tried it!!

Comment: This is not working properly, It doesnot show my all apps installed on device, it uses iTunes API, so app installed by user/developer are not shown in this list

Comment: @Mr.Mehul Thakkar, i checked with iOS 7 only, i didnt tried with iOS 8

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by using the following:

```
 Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
 SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace");

 NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:selector];

 SEL selectorALL = NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications");

 NSMutableArray *Allapps = [workspace performSelector:selectorALL];

 NSLog(@"apps: %@", Allapps);
```

And then by accessing each element and splitting it you can get your app name, and even the Bundle Identifier, too.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure if this was available back when the last answer was given or not (Prior to iOS 6)
Also this one is time intensive, yet simple:
Go into settings > Gen. >usage. The first category under usage at least right now is Storage.

It will show a partial list of apps. At the bottom of this partial list is a button that says "show all apps".
Tap that and you'll have to go through screen by screen, and take screenshots (Quick lock button and home button takes a screenshot). 
I'm doing this now and I have hundreds of apps on my iPhone. So it's going to take me a while. But at least at the end of the process I'll have Images of all my apps.

Comment: That's not really a programmatic approach though :-)

Comment: This was available before as well, but I wanted to do this programatically. Anyways, thanks for taking time to provide an answer :)