# Is it possible to get to installed app list on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get list of installed applications on iphone objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645365/get-list-of-installed-applications-on-iphone-objective-c)

Is it possible to get to installed app list on iPhone device.. if possible
how can i get applications list that are installed in iPhone

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can not do this with public api. You could create a list of url schemes and test if the app can open them but some apps does not have url schemes.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. Because it is handled by apple's private api's. Well this can be tried on Jailbroken devices anyways.

Anyways, you can check if a specific application is installed on device using appdelegate's canopenurl method. That will take the URL of the method & if it is there in app you can open that application via your application.

Hope it helps.

Comment: how can i use canOpenURL method and open that app via my application...

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/   Check it. This link will help you.