# How to programmatically query an iphone App's installation info?

Tags: iphone

My friend is trying to write a Windows application that can query an iPhone (non-jailbroken) for its installed APPs (such as logo/size/installer's AppleID/etc), and backup/restore the Apps. Some vague info got online is to use iTunesMobileDevice.dll, but no detailed information. Can someone share some knowledge about how to do this? Or is there any open source project that can achieve this goal? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to create a list of applications on an iPhone, and it is also impossible to copy the applications, especially on a non-jailbroken iPhone.

You can check if a certain application is installed, however unhelpful it is towards your goal: [handleOpenUrl](http://handleopenurl.com/).

See also: [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614114/get-list-of-installed-apps-on-iphone).

Comment: Thanks so much! I will let my friend know.