# How an app to know what other apps have been installed in the device

Tags: ios, sandbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get list of installed apps on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614114/get-list-of-installed-apps-on-iphone)

Is there a way to know what other apps have been installed in an iPhone or other iOS devices?. I know that all ios apps are sandboxed so this may be impossible on a non-jailbroken device. but there is an App can do that.!not jailbroken (see image), How can it know all the apps I have installed?

[image]

Comment: I know there is the same question have been asked on iOS 4.0 SDK, but on iOS 5 or later the answer may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using iHasApp framework for my projects, and it works fine. You can get the code [here](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp).