# Can an iOS app determine the other apps that are on the iphone and what permissions they have?

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions

I'm wondering if an app has access to the info that shows the other apps on the phone and what permissions they have (i.e. access to your location, contacts, etc).

Could I create an iOS app with a feature that displays other apps and their permissions? I know the user can view this info via settings, but I'm wondering if it can be organized and displayed by an app.

a similar question was asked here:
[How an app to know what other apps have been installed in the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798353/how-an-app-to-know-what-other-apps-have-been-installed-in-the-device)

but the solution method (iHasApp) only works for about 50% of apps, and doesn't address seeing the permissions of those apps.

Thanks!

Comment: @Putz1103 wrong duplicate. That answer was for Android. For iOS the answer is No as of iOS7. Not sure about iOS 8 with it app-collaboration feature.

Comment: Thank you @SamBudda! Looking forward to iOS8 for sure

Comment: The answer is no and I can't see this ever changing. Apple takes privacy pretty seriously and while you may have only good intentions for your app there is a potential for abuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't access apps data due to sandbox structure upto iOs7.