# executing external apps on Android/iOS with Ionic

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, uri

In my Ionic app I try to execute various apps just per button click. The following function launchs Skype on Android and iOS. The URI from Skype for Androis is `com.skype.raider` and for iOS is `skype://`

```
function launchSkype() {
    var scheme;

    if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
        scheme = 'skype://';
    } else if (device.platform === 'Android') {
        scheme = 'com.skype.raider';
    } else if (device.platform === 'wp') {
        scheme = 'skype:';
    } else if (device.platform === 'windows8') {
        scheme = 'skype:';
    }

    navigator.startApp.check(scheme, function(message) { /* success */
        navigator.startApp.start(scheme, function(message) {
        }, function(error) { /* error */
            alert("Skype could not be started!");
        });
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Skype is not installed!");
    });
}
```

It's important to find the Intent links (URI) of the respective applications and run these on Android/iOS.  **I have difficulties in finding the URI links of iOS**. On Android, it is easy to find. On Google Play the respective App ID is to find in the address bar.

My question is, **where can I find the app ids of iOS applications for launching**? I'll have the same function exploited for other apps. I just need the ids.

I need eg for precisely the Ids of these (native) app for the execution:

1. URI of native "Email app" (Android / iOS)
2. URI of native "Address Book" (Android / iOS)
3. URI of native "My Documents" (Android / iOS)

**Edit:**

So, i find a app for android named **Package Name Viewer** which give the package name of all installed apps. Is there something similar for iOS? With the app I have found the following package name:

1. `com.android.email`
2. `com.android.contacts`
3. `com.sec.android.app.myfiles`

The second point, so `com.android.contacts` doesn't show directly to the contacts on Android. Which link would be correct that displays directly stored  contacts on the device?

Comment: Hi @Ramosta I have provided an answer to your question. If you think it is correct can you please mark it as the correct answer so the topic will be closed? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not allow this behaviour. There has been efforts to try to circumvent this, and as according to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4614190/1336244)[1] you can just try to see if the URI can be opened

Cited from the other answer:

> - if the app is known to handle URLs of a certain type
> - by using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"thisapp://foo"]
>
> You can get a list of apps and URL schemes from [here](http://handleopenurl.com/).