# Get access to all installed Apps on iPhone

Tags: ios

I want to display all apps there was installed on the iPhone in a UITableView in my App and then I would like to display the Internet usage of each apps there are installed. Is that Possible?

Comment: First of all, why would you do that? Because if you go to the settings you can see the usage. Secondly for my knowledges you can't do that because Apple won't let you into other app's info.

Comment: You are dreaming, you can't do that

Comment: Yes I know that but I would like to make an app there the user can set a data limit for each app and become then a remind when its out is that possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of installed apps on iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614114/get-list-of-installed-apps-on-iphone)

Comment: Oke then it´s not possible Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you work for twitter? Prior to iOS 9 there was a way to discover installed apps, but that has since been removed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. Apple specifically prevents apps from learning about other installed apps.